# Wordpress not show photo on correct position in page.php

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, photo

Ok, I have a problem and I don't know how to solve problem. I made a wordpress template (using a bootstrap) and problem is in page.php. I made new page (About me) and put inside tekst and photos but photos are not align like in the dashboard. For example I give that photo is aling on the right 
[How test is formatted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpOa5.png)

but in the browser in the page is like this

[How looks](http://www.osmica.hr/o-nama/)

My code for page.php is:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php while( have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
<section class="row title-bar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>  
<section class="row main">
    <div class="container">
        <?php if( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar')): ?>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                            <?php else: ?>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                            <article class="page" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px">
                                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                                            </article>
                                            <div class="clr"></div>
                                    </div>
                            <?php if( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar')): ?>        
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar'); ?>
                                    </div>  
                            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>      
        </div>
</section>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php get_footer('single'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress editor uses styles loaded in the backend (WP Dashboard) only. The right aligned images use a CSS class `.alignright` and the opposite for left aligned images.

Since you're using base Bootstrap and your own custom styles, you haven't styled your frontend to reflect what WordPress editor does. That said, to make the right aligned images look almost same as the you see it in editor, add the following code to your `style.css`

```
.alignright {
    float: right;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Yes It is correct answer thank you. If I understand I have also put in css .alignleft, and all other alings. I can not give answer usefull because my reputation is to low. But I accepted this like answer

Comment: Glad that it was useful.